# rspec-rails+capybara NoMethodError:undefined method `create'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm learning ruby on rails, but I have a problem that I couldn't solve by myself. Any one can help me?

when I run:bundle exec rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb， I got this error:

```
Failure/Error: @user = create(:user)  NoMethodError:
       undefined method `create' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::User::PropertiesShouldNotNil:0xb807450>
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Gemfile:

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '5.0.0.rc2'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.3.0'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'alipay', '~> 0.10.0' #支付宝接口
gem 'capistrano-rails', :group => :development
gem 'capistrano-passenger', :group => :development
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'
# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  #gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem "capybara"
end
group :development do
  gem 'web-console', group: :development
end
```

spec/rails_helper.rb:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end
```

app/models/user.rb

```
app/models/user.rb
  has_many :recipients
end
```

spec/models/user_spec.rb:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  context "properties should not nil" do
    before do
      @user = create(:user)
    end

    subject{ @user }

    it { should respond_to(:name) }
    it { should respond_to(:passwd) }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is because the `create` method you are trying to call is usually defined in the `FactoryGirl` class. [FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) is a Ruby gem that lets you define custom factories to instantiate your application-specific models.

As you may need to integrate this gem in your Rails app, I suggest that you use the [`factory_girl_rails` gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails). Simply add the gem declaration into the `:test` group of your *Gemfile*, like as follows:

```
group :development, :test do
  # Here go other gem declarations...
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end
```

Once you have included this gem in your project, you'll need to define the factories for your models (in this case, your `User` model) in order to specify the way you want your test instances to be built or created. I recommend you read this basic [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md) on how to define factories with `FactoryGirl` (I read this doc over and over).

In advance, I could tell you that the factories are usually defined under the `spec/factories` folder (in cases like this, that you are using `RSpec`) and have a common structure. In this case, your `User`factory would be defined in a file like *spec/factories/user.rb* and be like:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    # Here you assign values to the different attributes, like:
    #  username "username"
    #  password "pass"
    #  ...
  end
end
```

I use the [`faker` gem](https://github.com/stympy/faker) with `FactoryGirl` a lot, because it lets me create random values for names, telephone numbers, emails, etc in a way that are always different but make sense. Take a look at its documentation in case you are interested in it.

Hope these can help you solve your problem!

Comment: Thank you Daniel Ruiz, your answer help me solve my problem.